# Consumir REST API a partir de uma PL (PostgreSQL 11)

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, pl-sql, dbase

Olá,

Estou atuando em um projeto no qual devo construir uma PL que deverá consumir um serviço REST (retorno em JSON). Olhando a documentação do PostgreSQL, não encontrei funções equivalente a *UTL_HTTP* do Oracle.

Encontrei alguns tutoriais em que o DBA construiu a PL usando PL/Python para fazer requisições HTTP.

O PostgreSQL não tem suporte nativo a requisições HTTP?

Comment: Não posso afirmar, mas suspeito que não. Me surpreende que Oracle tenha. Uma requisição HTTP sem threads acabaria com a responsividade do banco. Se você precisa fazer isso, pode ser indício que há algo muito errado com o seu requisito. Quem deveria fazer chamadas a APIs web é a aplicação no backend. Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12669205/2241463

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução baseada é o PostgREST. Essa ferramenta atua fornecendo a API, possui suporte HTTP e atende a este tipo de requisição.

Um detalhe importante: As respostas das requisições são devolvidas em JSON